# Quantize using wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I want to retrieve a list of `n` average colors in an image using Python Wand. From the command line, this can be achieved using Imagemagick directly.

```
convert image.jpg -colors $n -format %c histogram:info:-
```

Wands `Image` objects have a histogram dictionary, from which the list of colors can be accessed. But I cannot find a command to quantize the colors.

Can Wand perform color reduction? Is there a binding for `-colors`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe a Quantize image method is [planned for future release](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/pull/152). It might be worth checking out planned update branches on [github](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/branches). If you can't wait, and not comfortable working on development builds, you can access [ImageMagick's C library](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickQuantizeImage) directly through [wand's API](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.7/wand/api.html) & [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library
import ctypes

# Register C-type arguments
library.MagickQuantizeImage.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p,
                                        ctypes.c_size_t,
                                        ctypes.c_int,
                                        ctypes.c_size_t,
                                        ctypes.c_int,
                                        ctypes.c_int
                                       ]   
library.MagickQuantizeImage.restype = None

def MyColorRedection(img,color_count):
  '''
     Reduce image color count
  '''
  assert isinstance(img,Image)
  assert isinstance(color_count,int)
  colorspace = 1 # assuming RGB?
  treedepth = 8 
  dither = 1 # True
  merror = 0 # False
  library.MagickQuantizeImage(img.wand,color_count,colorspace,treedepth,dither,merror)

with Image(filename="image.jpg") as img:
  MyColorRedection(img,8) # "img' has now been reduced to 8 colors
```